# Development Library Packages for CS Department server

Tags: package, libraries

I'm an assistant sysadmin for my university's CS department. We're prepping a new image for our servers used by students and faculty for classes, personal use, etc. I'm looking for recommendations for development library packages to install on these machines.

The servers are running ubuntu. (Not my decision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

netpbm is remarkably useful, even if it isn't a development library per-say. It's an easy file format and graphics work is good for a lot of earlier CS classes (and some later ones ;) ).

ncurses (yes, I used it)
readline
lapack

just a start. hope you find stuff the students like!